# Need to change SQL query for a temporary result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a temporary result for just a query. If substring condition true, I want to lower its car_performance value by %10 (car_performance = car_performance*0.9;) and compare this substring true cars against others BUT ONLY FOR THE QUERY, I don't want to change the real data in SQL database.

So I thought I need to get this data to a new temporary table with lowered car_performance values but I can't figure out how to write it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM car_list 
     IF SUBSTRING(car_model, 9, 1) = '3'` 
        car_performance = car_performance*0.9; 
ORDER BY car_performance ???
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I did correctly understand you. Correct me if I am wrong. Do you want to select all cars that respect condition `SUBSTRING(car_model,9,1) = 3` and print their performance like 0.9*performance? If so, you can use this statement:

```
SELECT car_model, car_performance*0.9 as car_performance
FROM car_list
WHERE SUBSTRING(car_model, 9, 1) = '3'
```

I also recommend you to take a SQL course. It is easier and faster to understand after you learn the basics. There are a lot of great free resources online.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need a comparison for whole set of cars depending on a condition for some of them, and leaving the rest as they are. If so, `CASE WHEN ... THEN .. ELSE ...` conditional statement will do the trick such as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(car_model, 9, 1) = '3' 
            THEN car_performance * .9 
            ELSE car_performance 
             END AS car_performance
  FROM car_list 
ORDER BY car_performance
```